# Method in a web service runs multiple times (depending on the button click) | Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am consuming a method in a web service soap. It runs smoothly when the button is being tapped once, a dialog box will be popped up. On the second button tap, the dialog box will be showed twice. On the third button tap, the dialog box will be showed thrice. And so on....

```
 case Resource.Id.btnLogin:

                hud = KK.Create(this.Activity)
                     .SetSize(75, 75);
                hud.Show();

                loginClick(); //Function for button click

                break;


private void loginClick(){
        hud.Dismiss();
        if (TextUtils.IsEmpty(txtID.Text.ToString()) || TextUtils.IsEmpty(txtPass.Text.ToString()))
        {
            AlertMessageView.showAlertDialog(this.Activity, "Error", GetString(Resource.String.Msg33), "OK", null, null, null);
        }
        else if (txtID.Text.ToString().Trim().Length < 12)
        {
            tilID.Error = GetString(Resource.String.Msg8);
        }
        else
        {

            service.VerifyLoginAsync("user", "Password", txtID.Text.ToString(), txtPass.Text.ToString());
            service.VerifyLoginCompleted += Service_VerifyLoginCompleted;
        }
    }
```

Consuming web service method Verify Login:

```
private void Service_VerifyLoginCompleted(object sender, IDWebService.VerifyLoginCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("IsValid" + e.Result.isValid);

        if (e.Result.isValid == true)
        {

            #region firstLogin
            if (e.Result.isfirstlogin == "1")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Redirect Verification page");

                AlertMessageView.showAlertDialog(this.Activity, "Invalid login", "Is it your first time to login?", "YES", "NO", dialogFTL, null);

                //var intent = new Intent(this.Activity, typeof(OTPActivity));
                //StartActivity(intent);
                //Activity.Finish();


            }
            else
            {
                #region lockedout
                if (e.Result.islockedout == "1")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error Msg");
                    AlertMessageView.showAlertDialog(this.Activity, "Account has been locked", "Kindly coordinate with employer", "OK", null, null, null);

                }

                else {

                    #region forgotPass
                    if (e.Result.isforgotpass == "1")
                    {
                        AlertMessageView.showAlertDialog(this.Activity, "Invalid Password", "Please change your password.", "YES", "CANCEL", dialogFTL, null);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        #region enabled
                        if (e.Result.isenabled == "1")
                        {
                            #region validpass
                            if (e.Result.isValidPassword == true)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Number:" + e.Result.number);
                                Console.WriteLine("First Name:" + e.Result.fname);

                                fname = e.Result.fname;
                                number = e.Result.number;
                                GenerateOTP();

                                var intent = new Intent(this.Activity, typeof(OTPLoginActivity));
                                StartActivity(intent);
                                Activity.Finish();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Failed Date Login");
                                #region morethan24
                                if (e.Result.isMoreThan24Hrs == true)
                                {

                                    loginCounter = 0;
                                    MemberFailedLogin(loginCounter.ToString());
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    loginCounter = Convert.ToInt32(e.Result.failedattempt) + 1;

                                    if (loginCounter < 3)
                                    {
                                        //loginCounter = 0;
                                        //LogActivity Method
                                        MemberFailedLogin(loginCounter.ToString());
                                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Login" + loginCounter);
                                        //MemberFailedLogin(loginCounter.ToString());
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine("Account has been locked" + loginCounter);

                                        MemberLockAccount();


                                        AlertMessageView.showAlertDialog(this.Activity, "Account has been locked", "Kindly coordinate with employer.", "OK", null, null, null);


                                    }


                                }
                                #endregion


                                //AlertMessageView.showAlertDialog(Activity, null, "Invalid login", "OK", null, null, null);

                                //return;


                            }
                            #endregion 
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            AlertMessageView.showAlertDialog(this.Activity, "Account disabled", "Please contact your employer.", "OK", null, null, null);

                        }
                        #endregion

                    }
                    #endregion
                }
                #endregion

            }
            #endregion
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid");

            AlertMessageView.showAlertDialog(this.Activity, null, "Invalid Credentials", "OK", null, null, null);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Disable the button at the beginning of your loginClick method and enable it at the end.

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks for your response. But can explain your answer further?

Answer (score 0):

Well it is quite simple;

Assuming that `LoginButton` is your button object then you need to do something like this:

```
private void loginClick(){
   LoginButton.Enabled=False;
   .....
   LoginButton.Enabled=True;
}
```

Comment: I've done this but it still shows up depending on the user click. First button click -> Dialog box shows up once -> Clicks OK -> Dialog box exits Second button click -> Dialog box shows up twice -> Clicks OK twice coz of 2 dialog boxes that showed up -> Dialog boxes exits Third button click -> Dialog box shows up thrice -> Clicks OK thrice coz of 3 dialog boxes that showed up -> Dialog boxes exits ...and so on... :(

Answer (score 0):

> But can explain your answer further?

Temporary disable the Button from receiving additional user touches while you are processing the first touch.

Example:

```
string orgText = button.Text;
Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnLogin
try
{
    button.Enabled = false;
    button.Text = "Processing";
    hud = KK.Create(this.Activity).SetSize(75, 75);
    hud.Show();
    loginClick(); //Function for button click
}
finally
{
    button.Text = orgText;
    button.Enabled = true;
}
break;
```

Comment: I've done this but it still shows up depending on the user click.

First button click -> Dialog box shows up once -> Clicks OK -> Dialog box exits

Second button click -> Dialog box shows up twice -> Clicks OK twice coz of 2 dialog boxes that showed up -> Dialog boxes exits

Third button click -> Dialog box shows up thrice -> Clicks OK thrice coz of 3 dialog boxes that showed up -> Dialog boxes exits

...and so on... :(